# Resolving PE SxS imports Windows

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable, winsxs

I'm in the middle of writing my own version of the Windows Loader (albeit a very simple version) and thus far things have worked out fairly well. However, I've run into a little snag when it comes to recursively walking the Import table for the loaded module.

For most dependencies, things work out well and I can simply recursively load the module. However, for some dependencies, this just breaks the target process. Upon further investigation I realized that this is because of Windows Side-by-side assemblies. Essentially, the dependency in the loaded PE was a different SxS version of the module being used in the target process.

In one case, the DLL I was loading referenced msvcr90.dll, but the target process was using an earlier version of the runtime: msvcr71.dll.

Now, the windows loader can handle this fine, so there's obviously a "correct" way to do this. I've read up a bit on Activation Contexts, but they haven't really helped me grasp the issue.

Calling LoadLibrary itself doesn't resolve the dll to the correct version either

```
LoadLibraryW(L"msvcr90.dll");
```

Simply returns 0. Does anyone know

> a) How to detect if an import is a SxS assembly
>
> b) How to resolve the import into the correct SxS version for the process.

I'm really stumped on how to do this. I know most of the PE file format from research now, but I'm pretty sure the SxS is beyond the scope of PE structure.

If you need any more info, just comment. The executable doesn't have an external manifest, and its embedded manifest doesn't specify the runtime version. It does, however, contain a copy of msvcr71.dll in its working directory, if that helps anyone at all.

Cheers.

Comment: You are just seeing the top of the iceberg that sank the Titanic.  You will also have to deal with manifests, either embedded as a resource or provided on disk, publisher policies, binding redirects, registry-free COM, dynamic activation through CreateActCtx, custom DLL search paths set with SetDllDirectory.  The documentation is lousy.

Comment: @HansPassant I managed to get this working. You were right in that it was just the tip of the iceburg haha. In the end I had to write a Resource Walker to locate the `.dll`'s internal manifest (RT_MANIFEST). Next, I had to write an assembly stub that handled all the `Activation Context` stuff. Of course, I could've simply written it in C++ and wrapped it in a .dll with static linkage (i.e no SxS), then used it to load all the next libraries, but it seemed overkill so I did it in assembly. Basically, I feed the assembly function a null-delimited string of needed dependencies...

Comment: as well as the path to the manifest (I extracted the internal manifest to a temp file, `CreateActCtx` needs a path to the manifest). It then creates the activation context, runs through the null-delimited list of modules and calls `GetModuleHandle` on each. If `GetModuleHandle` returns `0`, it proceeds to call `LoadLibrary`. If still 0, it exits the function. I know I skipped over the hardest part by simply using `LoadLibrary` within the `Activation Context`, but I only really wanted to use my own loader for the main dll, not its dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, SxS dependencies are beyound the scope of the PE Structure! As you know, the Import Tables of PE enumerate the dependencies **names** but not their versions. When handling these tables of dependencies, the Loader also look at the Manifest of the PE dependent images. Should a Manifest documents one or more libraries (e.g msvcr90, advapi32,....) the loader looks in winsxs folder to find the dependency. [Here an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88363/Retrieve-the-Assembly-Identities-from-a-Manifest-u) that gives an overview of this assembly and how to collect these information in C++.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to build the name of the WinSxs dependencie on your own. All you need to do is to "probe" using CreateActCtx. Should the loader find that the dependency, it will built the correct path (e.g. x86_microsoft-windows-msvcrt_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17744_none_d33c3413fd4084d9) for you!

Comment: Side-by-Side assemblies (WinSxs) are difficult to handle. I had this problem during my implementation of PeStudio (http://www.winitor.com)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's making things a bit more clear. The only thing is, how do you check if a given import name is WinSxS? I mean, in the manifest `Microsoft.VC90.CRT` is associated with `msvcr90.dll`, but how is this link established? If I first read the manifest to identify WinSxS compatible imports, how do I map them to a specific import name?

Comment: Okay, I figured the first thing would be to construct a list of all the possible WinSxS imports by first looking up the image's RT_MANIFEST resource, and resolving all possible WinSxS dependencies from that. However, I'm struggling to see how to convert the manifest info to a SxS directory. I don't know what the final identifier is in relation to the manifest i.e: `C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91` the `bcb86ed6ac711f91` bit isn't found in the manifest, so I'm not sure how to resolve that :/

Comment: It is the job of the loader (with the help of WinSxS Manager) to resolve the real path of the library. As mentioned in the article, the path depends on the language, public key token, etc.... Let the loader resolves this for you. Use Activation context Api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376620(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The point of this question is that I'm writing my own loader, so I can't just defer to the Windows loader to do this for me.

Comment: ok. but you can use the activation context api! did you try this?

Comment: Presumably the Activation Context has to be retrieved from the process doing the loading. Given that I'm writing this in C#, and loading into remote processes, I don't think it's going to be a simple task to get thread-local activation contexts from a remote process :/ I could do it with some less-than-desirable thread suspension and redirection, but I'd rather just reverse the resources for the RT_MANIFEST and resolve sxs paths from there.

Comment: You said it. I'm just going to parse the current images RT_MANIFEST resource (if present) and resolve SxS references from there. If it doesn't work, too bad :)

Comment: Negative, the process itself has already got a different SxS version of msvcr loaded. Is there any way to check if a SxS dependency is already loaded?

Comment: yes of course, just invoke GetModuleHandle with the name of the SxS dependency, if it is already loaded, you will get the handle to it.

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood the versioning. I ended up just having to do some really hacky messy stuff, but it's working now :3